# Can you change the photo in the Facebook share button popup window?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, share

I have a Facebook Like/Share button on a webpage.  When you click the Share button, a window pops up allowing you to share a message about the site.  There's a photo in the popup as well, which is derived from the webpage the button is on.

The problem is, that webpage shows a composite photo, an image on top of another image, and instead of showing the whole composite, the popup shows one piece of it.

Is there a way to use a different image entirely on the Facebook popup window, some specific image that's not present on the webpage?  I had thought the og:image meta tag would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Got it.  My problem is that the info I need from the Facebook Developer pages is either incomplete or not presented in a way I can understand.  So for the benefit of others in my boat:

1. It's not enough to add the Like/Share button javascript code and div tag (where you want the button to appear).  You also need to add a group of meta tags in the `<head>` section of your html page. (Note that in the Facebook Developers "Like Tag" page, the phrase "meta tag" does not appear.) The meta tag format is this:  `<meta property="og:type" content="website">`
2. There is apparently a lag between your adding these meta tags and Facebook finding them. Some have said this is because of the way Facebook caches its content.  In any case, you can bypass this lag by using the Facebook Debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/  You enter the URL of the page with the buttons, and it tells you what's missing from your code--and at the same time it now recognizes any new additions, like new meta tags.
3. It turned out I needed meta tags for og:url, og:title, og:image, og:site_name, og:type, and og:description.  I also discovered that the og:image tag needs an absolute url.
4. I found out about a lot of this not from Facebook but from here: http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags
5. The Debugger is now telling me I still need fb:admins and fb:app_id tags. To get those I apparently have to create a Facebook App, which I'd rather not do.  I hope it's not necessary.

Now that I've added these meta tags and run my page through the Debugger, I'm now getting the image I want showing in the Share window.